# Formatting to count data

Tags: r, reshape2

I have the following `data.frame`:

```
df = data.frame(a = sample(c(rep(1,23),rep(2,22), rep(3,43), rep(4, 12))), 
                b = sample(c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10), rep(3,20), rep(4, 60))), 
                c = sample(c(rep(1,40),rep(2,5), rep(3,30), rep(4, 25))))

table(df)
```

I'd like to run a model on these counts. A model of the following kind:

```
MCMCglmm(fixed = MyCount ~ a+b , random = c, data=new.df)
```

My question has to do with how to easily go **from `df` to the `new.df`** (data.frame which contains data expressed the right way). Or how to express 4 variables out of the three first in order to have a count variable of their interaction.

The variable fixed might be define doing `MyCount = c(table(df))`. But re-expressing `a`, `b` and `c` seem rather complicated to me.

What is the simplest solution? Maybe using the package `reshape`?

Comment: The current code throws errors. Post code that constructs a `new.df` object with the variable/column names

Comment: @Dwin I realized that I fixed the problem but obviously I did not succeeded to make the edit. Sorry about that. It is fixed now. The `new.df` object is the object I aim to construct. I'd like to re-express `df` into count data. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `as.data.frame.table` will construct a "Freq" column which I am renaming to 'MyCount';

```
> new.df <- setNames( as.data.frame(table(df)), c(names(df), "MyCount"))
> str(new.df)
'data.frame':   64 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ a      : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 ...
 $ b      : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
 $ c      : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ MyCount: int  1 2 0 0 1 0 2 2 0 3 ...
```

BTW, there is no package named "Reshape". Correct capitalization is part of learning R.